# split string error in a compiled VB.NET class

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm having some trouble compiling some VB code I wrote to split a string based on a set of predefined delimeters (comma, semicolon, colon, etc).  I have successfully written some code that can be loaded inside a custom VB component (I place this code inside a VB.NET component in a plug-in called Grasshopper) and everything works fine.  For instance, let's say my incoming string is "123,456".  When I feed this string into the VB code I wrote, I get a new list where the first value is "123" and the second value is "456".
However, I have been trying to compile this code into it's own class so I can load it inside Grasshopper separately from the standard VB component.  When I try to compile this code, it isn't separating the string into a new list with two values.  Instead, I get a message that says "System.String []".  Do you guys see anything wrong in my compile code?  You can find an screenshot image of my problem at the following link: [click to see image](http://www.liftarchitects.com/storage/downloads/splitstring_error.jpg)

**This is the VB code for the compiled class:**

```
Public Class SplitString
Inherits GH_Component
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("Split String", "Split", "Splits a string based on delimeters", "FireFly", "Serial")
End Sub
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentGuid() As System.Guid
    Get
        Return New Guid("3205caae-03a8-409d-8778-6b0f8971df52")
    End Get
End Property
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Internal_Icon_24x24() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Get
        Return My.Resources.icon_splitstring
    End Get
End Property
Protected Overrides Sub RegisterInputParams(ByVal pManager As Grasshopper.Kernel.GH_Component.GH_InputParamManager)
    pManager.Register_StringParam("String", "S", "Incoming string separated by a delimeter like a comma, semi-colon, colon, or forward slash", False)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub RegisterOutputParams(ByVal pManager As Grasshopper.Kernel.GH_Component.GH_OutputParamManager)
    pManager.Register_StringParam("Tokenized Output", "O", "Tokenized Output")
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub SolveInstance(ByVal DA As Grasshopper.Kernel.IGH_DataAccess)
    Dim myString As String
    DA.GetData(0, myString)

    myString = myString.Replace(",", "|")
    myString = myString.Replace(":", "|")
    myString = myString.Replace(";", "|")
    myString = myString.Replace("/", "|")
    myString = myString.Replace(")(", "|")
    myString = myString.Replace("(", String.Empty)
    myString = myString.Replace(")", String.Empty)

    Dim parts As String() = myString.Split("|"c)
    DA.SetData(0, parts)

End Sub
```

End Class

**This is the custom VB code I created inside Grasshopper:**

```
Private Sub RunScript(ByVal myString As String, ByRef A As Object)
myString = myString.Replace(",", "|")
myString = myString.Replace(":", "|")
myString = myString.Replace(";", "|")
myString = myString.Replace("/", "|")
myString = myString.Replace(")(", "|")
myString = myString.Replace("(", String.Empty)
myString = myString.Replace(")", String.Empty)

Dim parts As String() = myString.Split("|"c)
A = parts
```

End Sub

'

'

End Class

Comment: Image URL: file not found. :-(

Comment: yeah, I had wanted to post an image directly, but as a new user... I didn't have enough rep points.  I tried the link in explorer (if anyone still even uses that program) and it worked... but didn't in Firefox.  I can send it to anyone via email if they would prefer that method.  Email me at andy@liftarchitects.com

Answer (score 1):

Well, knowing nothing about Grasshopper, I'm just going to have to guess...

`System.String []` is what .NET would print if you called `ToString()` on a string array. So, I'm gonna guess that you've given Grasshopper an array where it wants a single string.

So, with a little further guessing, how 'bout we try:

```
Dim parts As String() = myString.Split("|"c) 
For I = 0 to parts.Length -1
    DA.SetData(I, parts[I])
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick response.  I wont be able to test the code out until I get home tonight (in about 6 hrs from now)... but I'll test it out.  I feel like I'm pretty close since it already works in one component, but not the compiled one... so this may indeed work.  I'll post my findings soon.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the code snippet you suggested... but it didn't quite work. I think the problem in the original code is that I'm trying to send a list of values (ie. parts) to a single output node.  So, when I use DA.SetData(0,parts) I'm writing a list of values to the first output node of my compiled component.  However, I think the problem is that the component doesn't know that parts is a list.  In the example I gave before, if my incoming string is "123,456" then my result split list should have two values (123 and 456).  I don't think I have declared parts to be a list.  Do you have any ideas on how to do this?  Again, if you click on the link in the original email (while using Internet Explorer... I'm not sure why Firefox isn't opening it) you should see a screenshot of the setup in the Grasshopper plugin which should help give you an idea of what's going on.  Thanks again for your help.